# C# "Tag" 4-byte Hex Chunks for reconstruction to original string later

Tags: c#, data-structures, hex, chunked-encoding

I am wrestling with a particular issue and like to ask for guidance on how I can achieve what I seek. Given the below function, a variable length string is used as input which produces a 4-byte Hex chunk equivalent. These 4-byte chunks are being written to an XML file for storage. And that XML file's schema cannot be altered. However, my issue is when the application which governs the XML file sorts the 4-byte chunks in the XML file. The result, is when I read that same XML file my string is destroyed. So, I'd like a way to "tag" each 4-byte chunk with some sort of identifier that I can in my decoder function inspite of the sorting that may have been done to it.

Encoding Function (Much of which was provided by (Antonín Lejsek)

```
private static string StringEncoder(string strInput)
    {
        try
        {
            // instantiate our StringBuilder object and set the capacity for our sb object to the length of our message.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strInput.Length * 9 / 4 + 10);
            int count = 0;

            // iterate through each character in our message and format the sb object to follow Microsofts implementation of ECMA-376 for rsidR values of type ST_LongHexValue  
            foreach (char c in strInput)
            {
                // pad the first 4 byte chunk with 2 digit zeros.
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    sb.Append("00");
                    count = 0;
                }

                // every three bytes add a space and append 2 digit zeros. 
                if (count == 3)
                {
                    sb.Append(" ");
                    sb.Append("00");
                    count = 0;
                }
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)c));
                count++;
            }
            // handle encoded bytes which are greater than a 1 byte but smaller than 3 bytes so we know how many bytes to pad right with.
            for (int i = 0; i < (3 - count) % 3; ++i)
            {
                sb.Append("00");
            }

            // DEBUG: echo results for testing.
            //Console.WriteLine("");
            //Console.WriteLine("String provided: {0}", strInput);
            //Console.WriteLine("Hex in 8-digit chunks: {0}", sb.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : StringEncoder has received null input.");
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : Please ensure there is something to read in the output.txt file.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For Example : This function when provided with the following input "coolsss" would produce the following output : 0020636F 006F6C73 00737300

The above (3) 8 digit chunks would get written to the XML file starting with the first chunk and proceeding onto the last. Like so,

0020636F
006F6C73
00737300

Now, there are other 8-digit chunks in the XML file which were not created by the function above. This presents an issue as the Application can reorder these chunks among themselves and the others already present in the file like so,

00737300
00111111
006F6C73
00000000
0020636F

So, can you help me think of anyway to add a tag of some sort or use some C# Data Structure to be able to read each chunk and reconstruct my original string despite the the reordering?

I appreciate any guidance you can provide. Credit to Antonín Lejsek for his help with the function above.

Thank you,
Gabriel Alicea

Comment: `catch (NullReferenceException e)` that is a really bad way to go because you are swallowing all NRE bugs that way and pretend they are expected cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will adjust that accordingly.

Comment: Do you know the maximum value of each chunk? If so, do you know how many chunks you might possibly have to keep track of? If so, you might be able to prepend a tag and ordinal to the chunk and extract this information later for reconstruction.

Comment: @Randy, Thanks for your time. I'll try to answer your questions by saying each chunk is randomly generated by the application for the exception of what I am inserting into the XML file which is effectively a string of variable length. So, with that said, I am not sure I can ascertain a maximum value to each chunk. Similarly - as the string can vary in length, the amount of chunks I am inserting will vary... The only constant with every chunk is the first byte must be "00". Can you provide an example of a tag and ordinal?

Comment: I was thinking you could use the first 2 hex-digits of the chunk to represent the tag and original. Does each chunk have to start with 00?

Comment: @Randy, Yep. Every chunk must start with a 00. However, the second byte could be made to be a tag and ordinal as per your suggestion...

Comment: I finally had some time today to update my answer. I know the first go was a bit vague so I hope the updated version provides some additional clarity as to how this might work.

Comment: @Randy, Thank you for your suggestion. I can see that it makes sense. However, I am not a super strong code guru. So far, I'm learning by seeing code implemented. Could you provide an example of code that implements the concepts you propose?

Comment: Sure, do yo know if the strings can exceed 16 characters in length? If so, then I would have to eliminate the checksum.

Comment: @Randy certainly. So long as the encoded string result follows the same 8-digit chunk format noted above with the first byte being comprised of "00" the input string length itself should be able to vary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am reluctant to suggest this as a proposed solution because it feels a bit too hackish for me.

Having said that; I suppose you could leverage the second byte as an ordinal so you can track the chunks and "re-assemble" the string later.

You could use the following scheme to track your chunks.

```
00XY0000
```

Where the second byte `XY` could be split up into two 4-bit parts representing an ordinal and a checksum.

```
X = Ordinal
Y = 16 % X
```

When reading the chunks you can split up the second byte into two words just like above and verify that the checksum aligns for the ordinal.

This solution does introduce a 16 character constraint on string length unless you eliminate the checksum and use the entire byte as an ordinal for which you can increase your string lengths to 256 characters.